# How would you describe this sketch? Is she hanging from / on to a man's arm?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, prepositions, vocabulary

[image: a very rough sketch of a girl (?) hanging on a man's muscular arm]

How would you describe this picture?

> "A girl is hanging **on** to a guy's arm"?

Or is it

> "A girl is [hanging](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hang?q=hang%2B) **from** a …"?

I'm really confused about the meaning and the image of
"hang + preposition", especially "[hang on to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hang-on)"

e.g. *The climber hung on to the ledge, praying for rescue*

and "hang from"

e.g. *A string of onions hung from a beam in the kitchen*

Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: To me it looks like she's *swinging* from his outstretched arm. https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=monkey+swinging+from+a+tree&imgrc=4YUg6nspImWZIM:&cad=h#imgrc=qoPuWwGZ_wu7SM:

Comment: *Hanging off* is another possibility.

Comment: @choster do you think the answer is easily intuitive from a non-native speaker's viewpoint? The fact that the OP is undecided between "hang on" and "hang from" shows it is a question about "word choice" and is, therefore, on topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I voted to migrate to ELL, but the majority did not.

Answer (score 1):

The second way is preferable. Without the picture, if you just said, "A girl is hanging on to a guy's arm," this could mean that a man and woman are walking side by side and the woman is clutching the man's arm. *Hanging from* adds the information of the woman's orientation with respect to the arm -- that she is beneath it.

Comment: Thanks so much! One more question though. If the guy stretched out his arm and said, "Hang from my arm", would that sound natural?

Comment: That's another question entirely, because it's a matter of opinion, and this forum doesn't like answers that are matters of opinion. And to give you a reasonable answer it, we'd need to know the context, too. For example, are these gym buddies, or are these two people that met each other at a party? You get the idea.

Comment: @xo_yyy No, it wouldn’t sound very natural. Not because the sentence is grammatically questionable, but because the _act_ is unnatural. People in general do not stretch out their arms and ask others to hang from them.

Comment: @JoshG Yes, I understand. Thank you. But what I want to know is if this sentence, "Hang from my arm", makes sense at all. Whatever the situation is, when someone stretches out his arm and says, "Hang from my arm", would you be able to understand what he's asking you to do?
Or would it be better to say, "Hang on to my arm"?

Comment: "Hang from my arm" works just fine, and in my opinion, is slightly better than "hang on to my arm," because the latter could mean that the person wants you to hold on tight as they pull you through a crowd. (You might tell a child to "hang on to my arm/hand" so they don't get lost in a crowd.)